# Google Drive API (server-side auth): how to access files by other apps

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a webapp, mywebapp.com, that successfully gets user permission to access Google Drive, mostly following examples for server-side flow here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

I successfully upload, then access those SAME files.

However, what I really want to do is access OTHER files, in particular Google Docs docs. Can this be done, and how?

If not, can it be done with client-side flow using regular JavaScript (not Google's hosted scripts)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Have you looked at the methods for listing and getting specific files? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#methods

Answer (score 0):

What your app can and cannot see is determined by the scope. The possible values are enumerated here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

Comment: Thanks, pinoyyid! Being a Google Drive noob, I had the scope set to ".../drive.file" which restricts the app to its own files. Changing to ".../drive" I can now see all other files.